# Is platform-independency of java really because of the combination of interpretation and compilation?

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, interpretation, platform-independent

I've seen a lot of online resources saying, Java is platform-independent because of its combination of using both interpretation and compilation.
Stage 1: Java compiles the source code into a byte code
Stage 2: this byte code is interpreted during the run time.

But, isn't Java platform-independent because byte code is platform-independent and it can be run on any machine that has a compatible JVM? Wouldn't Java still be platform-independent even if it's interpreted in both stages or compiled in both stages?

Comment: There is no way to be “interpreted in both stages” as the first stage of producing bytecode out of source code is compiling, by the meaning of the word. Of course, purely interpreted languages are usually platform independent too, but then, there aren’t two stages. So, compiling is not mandatory for a platform independent programming language, but neither is having bytecode, as having bytecode implies, as said, that there is a compilation stage.

Comment: Will it be platform dependent if compiled in both stages? And is an executable file that we usually get after compoling a C program a platform dependent file?

Comment: A lot of platform independent solutions have compilation in their second stage resp. the equivalent of it. The crucial point is that the compilation to native code has to happen on the target system. The file you get when compiling a C program is not platform independent. But open source systems delivering the C software as source code and compiling on the target platform can be considered platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the key to java's platform independence is bytecode and JVM is. When you compile a Java program, it is compiled into bytecode which is platform independent intermediate representation of the Java code.

JVM is responsible to execute the bytecode. Each operating system has its own implementation of JVM, which interprets the bytecode into machine code.

So, whether the language uses interpretation or compilation at any stage isn't the primary factor in its platform independence. It is the use of an intermediate, platform independent bytecode and system specific JVM that makes Java platform independent.